# Migrating from log4j 1.2 to log4j2

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j, log4j2

I am in the process of migrating my application from log4j 1.2 to log4j2-2.8.1 version.
Following is the existing 1.x configuration in **log4j.properties** file.

```
log4j.appender.JSERRORFILE=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.JSERRORFILE.File=${log4j.loglocation}/jserror.log
log4j.appender.JSERRORFILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.JSERRORFILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p %c - %m%n

log4j.logger.com.app.JavascriptLogger=ERROR,JSERRORFILE
log4j.additivity.com.app.JavascriptLogger=false
```

Converted this to equivalent xml configuration log4j2.xml :

```
<RollingFile name="JSERRORFILE" fileName="${log-path}/jserror.log">
<PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p %c - %m%n" />
</RollingFile>

<Logger name="com.app.JavascriptLogger" level="ERROR" additivity="false">
<AppenderRef ref="JSERRORFILE"/>
</Logger>
```

After conversion,I keep getting the following error :

```
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationException: Arguments given for element RollingFile are invalid
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the RollingFile appender when to rollover (trigger policy) and what the result of a rollover should look like.

If you want to rollover at some regular interval (TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy or CronTriggeringPolicy) you need to specify a `filePattern` containing a `SimpleDateFormat`-like string. If you want to rollover to prevent large files (SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy), you need to specify a `filePattern` containing `%i`.

The filePattern is the relative or absolute path of the location you want the old (rolled over) file to be moved to.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="MyApp" packages="">
  <Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="logs/app.log"
                 filePattern="logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
      <Policies>
        <CronTriggeringPolicy schedule="0 0 0 * * ?"/>
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="250 MB"/>
      </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="error">
      <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

The [cron expression](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/util/CronExpression.html) above fires once a day.

For details and more examples see the [RollingFile appender section](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender) of the user manual.

Comment: I would almost always recommend using the CronTriggeringPolicy as the replacement for the DailyRollingFileAppender instead of the TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy.

Comment: Updated the example. While making this change I noticed a few things. The Log4j2 manual needs concrete CronTriggeringPolicy concrete examples; cron expressions are not intuitive. Also, with TimeBased triggers, the trigger depends solely on the filePattern. With cron expressions it is the user's responsibility to sync the filePattern with the cron frequency (and keep them in sync during maintenance). This needs to be mentioned explicitly in the Log4j2 manual.

Comment: I captured the above in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-2128

Comment: Thanks Remko for detailed explanation.

Comment: After adding file pattern and timebased triggering policy,the error waved off.